# Sort a Object list by Object.propertyOne, and remove duplicate object by Object.propertyTwo at same time

Tags: java, sorting, collections, duplicates, depth-first-search

In a chessboard-based game DFS(depth first search) algorithm, i designed a Solution object for score compare such as

```
class Solution {
  double score;
  int currentPosition;
  byte[] board;
}
```

And we can quick sort the `List<Solution>` by `Comparator<Solution>` on score.

But give it a further try, if we want to control the memory usage in depth search, we must do duplication-remove.

Duplication such as same board and same currentPosition occurs, only leave the the score-highest one, remove the others.

So, is there some good algorithm in Java, for duplication-remove and score sorting on different properties of an object at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can override equals and hashCode and put them in a Set so that duplicates wont be added at all.

A good example can be found at : http://g-liu.com/blog/2014/10/implementing-custom-duplicate-detection-with-linkedhashset/

Comment: but what we can do, if one `Solution` with same hashCode but higher score, add to the set? And when board bigger, chess differs type more, the exact-hash compare is also some pain.

Comment: depends on your application logic,  do you want that to be considered duplicate ?

Comment: Solution with same board and currentPosition is duplicate. But when duplicate, the higher-score solution should be add to set, and replace the lower-score one.

Comment: Ah then you may be needing HashSet, the key is your currentPosition, if it exists, replace it with higher score one.

Comment: do I need to elaborate ?

Comment: So, first compares hash by hashset, then compares the score? is this really a fast approach?

Comment: sorry I meant HashMap, why not ?